# Why does my navigation bar header look different on only one page?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

My website project has a navigation bar at the top of the page. I made it on the index/home page and then copied and pasted it onto the other three pages so that there would be no differences. It looks the same on all of the pages, except for one page, where it has less margin/padding. I'll insert the pictures, but I've been told that the difference isn't clear unless you see it in real life on my screen.
[Correct margin/padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz5C1.png), [incorrect margin/padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gassR.png).

```css
.navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#bee7b8;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation img {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}

.navigation a {
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    color: #0c7c59;
    font-family: Nunito;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

.navigation li {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 32.5px;
    width: 295px;
}

.navigation a:link {
    color: #0c7c59;
}

.navigation a:visited {
    color: #28c191;
}

.navigation a:hover {
    color: #799b74;
}

.navigation a:active {
    color: #4c2e05;
}
```

```html
        <header>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <img class="navigation" src="https://i.imgur.com/x4oWsIA.png">
                <li><a href="index.html">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="regpay.html">REGISTER</a></li>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
```

I'm wondering if it's like this because I've tried using an image slideshow from W3 schools ([shown in this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73822009/w3-schools-image-slideshow-loads-with-images-stacked-on-top-of-each-other)), but removing that has not helped.

EDIT: I found out that linking to the w3 stylesheet is what causes it! IDK how to fix this though...

Comment: Can you show the other page's CSS and HTML?

Comment: @softcode Hi! The CSS and HTML for the other pages are the exact same because I copy-pasted the HTML code for the navbar onto all the pages, and they all refer back to the same CSS file. Would you like me to send the ENTIRE CSS and HTML for the pages? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: OK, I'll figure out how to answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you reset your CSS code? If you haven't then try this on top of your CSS code:

```
* {
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}
```

also, make sure you didn't miss anything when you copied the code.

Comment: Hi, I have checked again, nothing was missed when I copy-pasted it :( Also, I tried putting that in, but it change anything. Am I supposed to delete something else in my CSS to make that work? Thank you for trying though :)